# Catch SQL error in Node.js

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, error-handling

I have a pSQL table set to require unique values for some data, and I call to insert this data with the function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_location(
                                    name text,
                                    latitude numeric,
                                    longitude numeric,
                                    logo_url text = '')
RETURNS void AS $$
    INSERT INTO "PartySpot".locations (name, latitude, longitude, logo_url)
            VALUES (name, latitude, longitude, logo_url);

$$ LANGUAGE SQL VOLATILE STRICT;
```

I call this from an endpoint with node.js/express with:

```
pg.connect(connectionString, function(err, client, done) {

    var query = client.query("SELECT * FROM create_location($1,$2,$3,$4)", 
                    [req.body.name, 
                    req.body.latitude,
                    req.body.longitude,
                    req.body.logo_url]
                );

    query.on('row', function(row) {
        results.push(row);
    });

    query.on('end', function(row) {
        client.end();
        return res.json(results);
    });

    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

This works fine when the key is unique, but when testing the condition where it isn't, instead of the error being caught by the `if (err)` block, it goes unhanded and crashes the server.

What would be the proper way to handle such an occurrence? Is there a way to do it in the SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an `error` event handler on the query object to catch errors during query execution:

```
query.on('error', function(err) {
  console.log('Query error: ' + err);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Function `client.query` takes three parameters: `(query, params, function (err, result){})`.

The third one gives you a callback to provide the error context during the query execution, plus the result.